# Create/remove elements on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
if (data.response) {
    $("#product-create-step-2 input:last").after('<div class="variation_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="has_variations" id="has_variations" /> Posee variaciones?</div>');
} else {
    console.log("false");
    $("#product-create-step-2 input:last").remove('#variation_checkbox');
}
```

What is happening is:

1. When `data.response` is true it creates the element several times and I need to create only one time and don't know how
2. When `data.response` is false element previously create never is removed and don't know why

Any help?

**UPDATE**

I create the element as follow:

```
<div id="has_variation" style="display:none">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="has_variations" id="has_variations" /> Has variations?
</div>
```

And then change my code to:

```
$("div.has_variation").toggle(data.response);
```

Is not supposed that if `data.response` is true the element should show and if `data.response` is false the element should hide? I missing something?

Comment: the selector is selecting an input rather than what you're trying to remove.

Comment: @KevinB I trying to remove the element from where it was created before

Comment: Right, but that isn't what your code says.

Comment: Create a jQuery object(cache it), append/insert it, then use the cached variable and remove it.

Comment: @undefined Hmm my jQuery level is not so god, any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`variation_checkbox` is a class.. "#" is used for id & dot is used for classes.

```
$("#product-create-step-2").find('.variation_checkbox').remove();
```

[js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/BXaq5/)

Comment: I fixed that part but for some reason still not working `data.response`takes `false` but `div.variation_checkbox` remains

Comment: Is hard for me since values are generated from DB and mostly Symfony2 functions

Comment: I also added a jsfiddle demo to my answer.. use find() it should work

Answer (score 1):

Your `div` is being attached *after* the input. Your selector `$("#product-create-step-2 input:last").remove('#variation_checkbox');` is looking *inside* the input.

Try this instead:

```
$("#product-create-step-2 input:last").next('.variation_checkbox').remove();
```

**edit** changed `#variation_checkbox` to `.variation_checkbox`.

Comment: Edited: changed #variation_checkbox to .variation_checkbox.

Comment: I've changed before and remains there never hide or destroy